# transforming cerbos conditions AST to ucast conditions

Tags: typeorm, abstract-syntax-tree, query-builder, cerbos

We are using [Cerbos](https://docs.cerbos.dev/cerbos/latest/index.html) as an authorization server and one of the features we want to use is the [queryPlanner](https://docs.cerbos.dev/cerbos/latest/api/index.html#resources-query-plan).

My ultimate goal is to be able to create a TypeORM "selectQueryBuilder" from the AST response that I'm getting.

The following AST is an example of a `queryPlanner` response that we might get from cerbos:

```json
{
  "operator": "and",
  "operands": [
    {
      "operator": "gt",
      "operands": [
        {
          "name": "request.resource.attr.foo"
        },
        {
          "value": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "operator": "or",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "eq",
          "operands": [
            {
              "name": "request.resource.attr.bar"
            },
            {
              "value": 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "operator": "and",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "eq",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "name": "request.resource.attr.fizz"
                },
                {
                  "value": 6
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "operator": "in",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "value": "ZZZ"
                },
                {
                  "name": "request.resource.attr.buzz"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought about utilizing [ucast](https://github.com/stalniy/ucast) library to translate this response to some "CompoundCondition" and then use the [@ucast/sql](https://github.com/stalniy/ucast/tree/master/packages/sql) package to create my `selectQueryBuilder`.

I believe that the condition should look something like this in my case:

```js
import { CompoundCondition, FieldCondition } from '@ucast/core'

const condition = new CompoundCondition('and', [
  new FieldCondition('gt', 'R.attr.foo', 4),
  new CompoundCondition('or', [
    new FieldCondition('eq', 'R.attr.bar', 5),
    new CompoundCondition('and', [
      new FieldCondition('eq', 'R.attr.fizz', 6),
      new FieldCondition('in', 'R.attr.buzz', 'ZZZ')
    ])
  ])
])
```

Then it should be very easy to create the queryBuilder:

```js
  const conn = await createConnection({
    type: 'mysql',
    database: ':memory:',
    entities: [User]
  });


  const qb = interpret(condition, conn.createQueryBuilder(User, 'u'));
}
```

I am just having trouble creating the needed function (AST to compoundCondition)...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help.

```
import { CompoundCondition, Condition, FieldCondition } from '@ucast/core';

export abstract class Expression {
  protected constructor() {
  }

  abstract renderCondition(): Condition;

  static create(json: any): Expression {
    const {
      operator,
      operands,
      name,
      value
    } = json;

    switch (operator) {
      case 'and':
        return AndExpression.create(operands);

      case 'or':
        return OrExpression.create(operands);

      case 'gt':
        return GreaterThanExpression.create(operands);

      case 'gte':
        return GreaterThanOrEqualToExpression.create(operands);

      case 'lt':
        return LesserThanExpression.create(operands);

      case 'lte':
        return LesserThanOrEqualToExpression.create(operands);

      case 'eq':
        return EqualToExpression.create(operands);

      case 'ne':
        return NotEqualToExpression.create(operands);

      case 'in':
        return InExpression.create(operands);

      default: {
        if (name && !value) {
          return NameExpression.create(name);
        }

        if (!name && value) {
          return ValueExpression.create(value);
        }

        throw new Error(`unsupported expression operator ${operator}`);
      }
    }
  }
}

export abstract class OpExpression extends Expression {
  protected constructor() {
    super();
  }

  abstract renderOperator(): string;
}

export abstract class BinaryExpression extends OpExpression {
  protected constructor(
    protected leftOperand: Expression,
    protected rightOperand: Expression
  ) {
    super();
  }

  override renderCondition(): Condition {
    const isLeftOperandName: boolean = this.leftOperand instanceof NameExpression;
    const isLeftOperandValue: boolean = this.leftOperand instanceof ValueExpression;

    const isRightOperandName: boolean = this.rightOperand instanceof NameExpression;
    const isRightOperandValue: boolean = this.rightOperand instanceof ValueExpression;

    if (isLeftOperandName) {
      const leftExpression: NameExpression = this.leftOperand as NameExpression;

      if (isRightOperandName) {
        const rightExpression: NameExpression = this.rightOperand as NameExpression;

        return new FieldCondition(this.renderOperator(), leftExpression.name, rightExpression.name);
      } else if (isRightOperandValue) {
        const rightExpression: ValueExpression = this.rightOperand as ValueExpression;

        return new FieldCondition(this.renderOperator(), leftExpression.name, rightExpression.value);
      }
    } else if (isLeftOperandValue) {
      const leftExpression: ValueExpression = this.leftOperand as ValueExpression;

      if (isRightOperandName) {
        const rightExpression: NameExpression = this.rightOperand as NameExpression;

        return new FieldCondition(this.renderOperator(), rightExpression.name, leftExpression.value);
      } else if (isRightOperandValue) {
        const rightExpression: ValueExpression = this.rightOperand as ValueExpression;

        return new FieldCondition(this.renderOperator(), rightExpression.value, leftExpression.value);
      }
    }

    return new CompoundCondition(this.renderOperator(), [
      this.leftOperand.renderCondition(),
      this.rightOperand.renderCondition()
    ]);
  }
}

export abstract class UnaryExpression extends OpExpression {
  protected constructor(
    protected operand: Expression
  ) {
    super();
  }

  override renderCondition(): Condition {
    return new CompoundCondition(this.renderOperator(), [
      this.operand.renderCondition()
    ]);
  }
}

export abstract class NaryExpression extends OpExpression {
  protected constructor(
    protected operands: Expression[]
  ) {
    super();
  }

  override renderCondition(): Condition {
    return new CompoundCondition(this.renderOperator(), this.operands.map((operand: Expression) => operand.renderCondition()));
  }
}

export class AndExpression extends BinaryExpression {
  protected constructor(
    leftOperand: Expression,
    rightOperand: Expression
  ) {
    super(leftOperand, rightOperand);
  }

  override renderOperator(): string {
    return 'and';
  }

  static create(json: any): AndExpression {
    const [leftOperand, rightOperand, ...otherOperands] = json;

    if (otherOperands.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error('too many operands for a binary expression');
    }

    return new AndExpression(
      Expression.create(leftOperand),
      Expression.create(rightOperand)
    );
  }
}

export class OrExpression extends BinaryExpression {
  protected constructor(
    leftOperand: Expression,
    rightOperand: Expression
  ) {
    super(leftOperand, rightOperand);
  }

  override renderOperator(): string {
    return 'or';
  }

  static create(json: any): OrExpression {
    const [leftOperand, rightOperand, ...otherOperands] = json;

    if (otherOperands.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error('too many operands for a binary expression');
    }

    return new OrExpression(
      Expression.create(leftOperand),
      Expression.create(rightOperand)
    );
  }
}

export class GreaterThanExpression extends BinaryExpression {
  protected constructor(
    leftOperand: Expression,
    rightOperand: Expression
  ) {
    super(leftOperand, rightOperand);
  }

  override renderOperator(): string {
    return 'gt';
  }

  static create(json: any): GreaterThanExpression {
    const [leftOperand, rightOperand, ...otherOperands] = json;

    if (otherOperands.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error('too many operands for a binary expression');
    }

    return new GreaterThanExpression(
      Expression.create(leftOperand),
      Expression.create(rightOperand)
    );
  }
}

export class GreaterThanOrEqualToExpression extends BinaryExpression {
  protected constructor(
    leftOperand: Expression,
    rightOperand: Expression
  ) {
    super(leftOperand, rightOperand);
  }

  override renderOperator(): string {
    return 'gte';
  }

  static create(json: any): GreaterThanExpression {
    const [leftOperand, rightOperand, ...otherOperands] = json;

    if (otherOperands.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error('too many operands for a binary expression');
    }

    return new GreaterThanOrEqualToExpression(
      Expression.create(leftOperand),
      Expression.create(rightOperand)
    );
  }
}

export class LesserThanExpression extends BinaryExpression {
  protected constructor(
    leftOperand: Expression,
    rightOperand: Expression
  ) {
    super(leftOperand, rightOperand);
  }

  override renderOperator(): string {
    return 'lt';
  }

  static create(json: any): LesserThanExpression {
    const [leftOperand, rightOperand, ...otherOperands] = json;

    if (otherOperands.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error('too many operands for a binary expression');
    }

    return new LesserThanExpression(
      Expression.create(leftOperand),
      Expression.create(rightOperand)
    );
  }
}

export class LesserThanOrEqualToExpression extends BinaryExpression {
  protected constructor(
    leftOperand: Expression,
    rightOperand: Expression
  ) {
    super(leftOperand, rightOperand);
  }

  override renderOperator(): string {
    return 'lte';
  }

  static create(json: any): LesserThanExpression {
    const [leftOperand, rightOperand, ...otherOperands] = json;

    if (otherOperands.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error('too many operands for a binary expression');
    }

    return new LesserThanOrEqualToExpression(
      Expression.create(leftOperand),
      Expression.create(rightOperand)
    );
  }
}

export class EqualToExpression extends BinaryExpression {
  protected constructor(
    leftOperand: Expression,
    rightOperand: Expression
  ) {
    super(leftOperand, rightOperand);
  }

  override renderOperator(): string {
    return 'eq';
  }

  static create(json: any): EqualToExpression {
    const [leftOperand, rightOperand, ...otherOperands] = json;

    if (otherOperands.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error('too many operands for a binary expression');
    }

    return new EqualToExpression(
      Expression.create(leftOperand),
      Expression.create(rightOperand)
    );
  }
}

export class NotEqualToExpression extends BinaryExpression {
  protected constructor(
    leftOperand: Expression,
    rightOperand: Expression
  ) {
    super(leftOperand, rightOperand);
  }

  override renderOperator(): string {
    return 'ne';
  }

  static create(json: any): NotEqualToExpression {
    const [leftOperand, rightOperand, ...otherOperands] = json;

    if (otherOperands.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error('too many operands for a binary expression');
    }

    return new NotEqualToExpression(
      Expression.create(leftOperand),
      Expression.create(rightOperand)
    );
  }
}

export class InExpression extends BinaryExpression {
  protected constructor(
    leftOperand: Expression,
    rightOperand: Expression
  ) {
    super(leftOperand, rightOperand);
  }

  override renderOperator(): string {
    return 'in';
  }

  static create(json: any): InExpression {
    const [operand, ...operands] = json;

    return new InExpression(
      Expression.create(operand),
      ValueExpression.create(
        operands
          .map((operand: any) => ValueExpression.create(operand))
          .map((valueExpression: ValueExpression) => valueExpression.value)
      )
    );
  }
}

export class NameExpression extends Expression {
  protected constructor(public name: string) {
    super();
  }

  override renderCondition(): Condition {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

  static create(name: string): NameExpression {
    return new NameExpression(name);
  }
}

export class ValueExpression extends Expression {
  protected constructor(public value: any) {
    super();
  }

  override renderCondition(): Condition {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

  static create(value: string): ValueExpression {
    return new ValueExpression(value);
  }
}
```